# touchpad not working after hibernate

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, systemd, touchpad, hibernate

I'm using an up to date Arch/Antergos Linux.

My touchpad stops working after resuming from hibernate. I seem to be affected by [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1442699) bug and I need to type `sudo rmmod i2c_hid; modprobe i2c_hid` after every resume to get the touchpad back to a working state.

I tried to automate that process by adding a script `fix-touchpad.sh` to `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep` so that it is run upon resume from hibernate:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $1 = post ]
then
    rmmod i2c_hid
    modprobe i2c_hid
fi
```

The script is being executed upon startup which I tested with `echo "something" > log.log` before and after the `if` test as well as just before `fi`. However it does not bring my touchpad back to live.

I also tested the script successfully with `sh fix-touchpad.sh post` after resume, and lo and behold my touchpad wakes up again.

Why doesn't the script fix the touchpad when it is run as part of the resume procedure?

Is there any other way to fix my touchpad?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why, but **the problem is trying to both remove and add the module when returning from hibernation**.

### Solution 1

I ran into the same problem as you, and your script `fix-touchpad.sh` didn't work until I tried removing the module before hibernation, and adding it back after.

Based in [this answer](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?294065-Removing-a-module-before-suspend-with-systemd&p=1669381#post1669381) at Fedora Forum, it could be something like :

```
$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/fix-touchpad.sh
#!/bin/bash
[ "$1" = "pre" ] && modprobe -r i2c_hid
[ "$1" = "post" ] && modprobe i2c_hid
exit 0
```

### Solution 2

I also found another way to execute code on hibernate/resume, and **it also did  only work when removing the module before hibernation**. As descibred in Arch's Wiki [Power management#Sleep hooks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Suspend/resume_service_files), you can create a systemd service that is triggered by the sleep service.

Based on the wiki instructions, I came up with the following:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/root-resume.service
[Unit]
Description=(un)load module i2c_hid when going to/from sleep
Before=sleep.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=modprobe -r i2c_hid
ExecStop=modprobe i2c_hid

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

The service should be enabled with `systemd enable root-resume`. Note that ExecStart will be executed before `sleep.target`, and ExecStop will be executed while resuming.

### Solution 3

Check out `systemd-suspend-modules` package at [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/systemd-suspend-modules/). It basically defines a service that executes **Solution 1** for every module listed in a user config file. It could be more appropriate for other modules as it "recursively unloads the given modules and all that depend on it" (https://github.com/parkouss/systemd-suspend-modules/blob/master/suspend-modules#L19).

Comment: Thanks for the instructions! I had to change `sleep.target` to `hibernate.service` to get it to work in my case and used bash scrips for ExecStart and ExecStop.