# Touchpad stopped working after hibernate on Thinkpad X1 Carbon

Tags: ubuntu, manjaro, touchpad, thinkpad, hibernate

I've got a  Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 9.

When I hibernate  on Ubuntu 21.10 or Pop!_OS 21.10 or Manjaro, the touchpad either stops working after resume or the cursor moves very choppy. Both with Wayland and xorg. Kernel on Ubuntu 21.10: 5.13.0-22.22; Pop!OS: 5.15.5-76051505-generic; Manjaro - unsure. I'm using Gnome.

Looking for a way to fix this, so that the touchpad is fully working post-resume.

I tried reloading the kernel module with:

```
sudo rmmod psmouse; sleep 2; sudo modprobe psmouse
```

I also tried dis-/enabling the xinput device:

```
xinput disable 'SYNA8008:00 06CB:CE58 Touchpad'; sleep 2; xinput enable 'SYNA8008:00 06CB:CE58 Touchpad'
```

And I also tried removing/loading the `i2c_hid` kernel module per [touchpad not working after hibernate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/519827/299465). I doubt that this actually did anything, to be honest. I used "solution 2":

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/root-resume.service
[Unit]
Description=(un)load module i2c_hid when going to/from sleep
Before=sleep.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=modprobe -r i2c_hid
ExecStop=modprobe i2c_hid

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

In syslog (Pop!_OS):

```
13269-Dec 29 17:15:11 a00c053 gnome-shell[107472]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 6f with keysym 6f (keycode 20).
13270:Dec 29 17:15:15 a00c053 systemd[1]: Starting (un)load module i2c_hid when going to/from sleep...
13271:Dec 29 17:15:15 a00c053 modprobe[178848]: modprobe: FATAL: Module i2c_hid is in use.
13272-Dec 29 17:15:15 a00c053 systemd[1]: root-resume.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
13273-Dec 29 17:15:15 a00c053 systemd[1]: root-resume.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
13274:Dec 29 17:15:15 a00c053 systemd[1]: Failed to start (un)load module i2c_hid when going to/from sleep.
13275-Dec 29 17:15:15 a00c053 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
13276-Dec 29 17:15:15 a00c053 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
13277-Dec 29 17:15:15 a00c053 systemd-sleep[178849]: Suspending system...
13278-Dec 29 17:15:15 a00c053 kernel: [16124.219516] PM: suspend entry (deep)
```

No changes.

With `xinput test 'SYNA8008:00 06CB:CE58 Touchpad'` I can see, that there ARE signals received when I use the touchpad. Compared to pre-hibernate, there are A LOT less signals.

The "joystick" "mouse" always works. But **I** am not compatible with the knob ;)

Answer (score 2):

**HEUREKA!**

For whatever reason, *suspend* was set to "***S3 Linux***" in the *BIOS*. After changing it to "***Windows/Linux***", the touchpad seems to be working just fine after a wakeup.

Ah… What a relief ;) Now the device is so much more useful ;)

Comment: This solution worked for me on a 2022 Lenovo X1 Carbon (10th Gen).

Answer (score 1):

Same issue on Thinkpad T13 G3. "Windows/Linux" suspend works, but drains half of the battery over night.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/423998)